# Where does the idea of counting crows come from?

Tags: origins, animals, superstition, astrology

According to [Learn Religions](https://www.learnreligions.com/the-magic-of-crows-and-ravens-2562511) and many astrology websites, the number of crows you see predicts the future:

> "Seeing just a single crow is considered an omen of bad luck. Finding
>   two crows, however, means good luck. (Three crows mean health, and
>   four crows mean wealth.) Yet spotting five crows means sickness is
>   coming, and witnessing six crows means death is nearby."

Where does this superstition come from?

Comment: This is discussed on Writing.SE - https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/42369/29719

Answer (score 6):

I did some quick searching and found this page recounting a British nursery rhyme, with the oldest version accounted to be:

> One for sorrow, 
>   Two for mirth, 
>   Three for a funeral 
>   And four for birth. 
>   <sub>SOURCE: [British Bird Lovers](https://www.britishbirdlovers.co.uk/articles/one-for-sorrow-magpie-nursery-rhyme) referencing *[Proverbs and Popular Saying of the Seasons](https://books.google.com/books?id=RgsJAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q&f=false)* by Michael Aislabie Denham</sub>

The rhyme appears to have several subsequent variations over the years.

The tradition of foretelling the future by the flight of birds is known as [Augury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augury), and was already ancient by the Classical period.